# HaShem's day, what is it refering to?

Tags: words, commentaries

I would like to know what Yom HaShem is refering to and when it will have it's impact

Isaiah 2:12 Yom L'HaShem Tzevaot
Ezekiel 13:5 Yom HaShem, 30:3
Isaiah 13:6 & 9
Joel 1:15, 2:1, 2:11, 3:4, 3:14
Amos 5:18-20
Obad 1:15
Etc..etc...

Comment: Please explain the question. Those sources give detailed descriptions. The question when this will happen is a separate question. If that is your intention please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

one of the earliest reference is in Isaiah 2:12

> "For the day of the LORD of hosts shall be upon every one that is
>   proud and lofty, and upon every one that is lifted up; and he shall be
>   brought low"

in context it refers to the day God will pull the curtain so to speak and reveal Himself to humanity as it continues there

> "And the loftiness of man shall be bowed down, and the haughtiness of
>   man shall be humbled, and the Lord alone shall be exalted on that day.
>   And the idols shall completely pass away. And they shall come into the
>   caves of the rocks and into the hollows of the earth, because of the
>   fear of the Lord and because of the splendor of His pride, when He
>   rises to break the earth"

Rashi - "when he rises" - on judgment day

Comment: Is Isaiah really earlier than Ovadiah?

Comment: I think @DoubleAA is right. Ovadiah was a contemporary of King Achav, while Yeshaya prophesied in the times of his son Chizkiah.

Comment: @DonielF Achav's son was Achaziah not Chizkiah. Chizkiya's father was Achaz. To be fair Yeshayah started as early as Uzziah, which is still later than Achav, who died in war with Yehoshafat.

Comment: @DoubleAA *facepalm* Yes, right. Melech Yehuda, Melech Yisrael. Always get those two guys confused.